# After hysterectomy does FSH secretion stop?

Tags: reproduction, endocrinology

This question came in an exam, and my reference book says yes, it does. But it hasn't explained why.

If the ovaries are also removed, then the menstrual cycle should stop. In absence of hormones oestrogen and progesterone, there would be no inhibitory effect on FSH, so its secretion should continue.
Or if it stops, then why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strictly defined, a hysterectomy is removal of only the uterus.  But sometimes the ovaries are also removed, depending on the reason for the surgery and age of the woman.

If the ovaries are also removed, there would no ovarian or uterine cycling, true.  But without the negative feedback effect of ovarian steroids (progesterone and estrogen), levels of both FSH and LH would be persistently, abnormally high.  The same happens in postmenopausal women (ovaries still present but no longer producing steroids) and spayed pets.

If the uterus is removed but the ovaries left in, the ovaries would continue to mature follicles that release estrogen, ovulate, luteinize and produce progesterone, etc, etc. Even though there is no uterus for the steroids to act on (and no menstruation), the steroids would feed back to the anterior pituitary gland and FSH/LH levels would fluctuate in the normal patterns.

Without the obvious sign of menstruation, it would be tricky for the woman still with ovaries to know whether or not she had reached menopause.  The first woman (ovaries removed) would be thrown into a 'surgical menopause', an abrupt (and nasty) withdrawal of all ovarian steroids.

Comment: Could you add sources (references to papers, books, websites etc.) to allow users to background read on your answer?

Comment: It would be better if you could add some sources. I had searched Google, but did not find satisfactory results.

Answer (score 0):

It's been already shown that women subjected to hysterectomy but retaining ovaries reach menopause earlier than intact women, so hysterectomy may have an effect on the secretion and feedback pattern of FSH and LH. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3223258/

If what Heidi says is true, ie "If the uterus is removed but the ovaries left in, the ovaries would continue to mature follicles that release estrogen, ovulate, luteinize and produce progesterone, etc, etc. Even though there is no uterus for the steroids to act on (and no menstruation), the steroids would feed back to the anterior pituitary gland and FSH/LH levels would fluctuate in the normal patterns.", it would mean that steroids acting on the uterus would do their job and get back to the blood stream and exert the feedback effect on the hypothalamus.

What happens after they have entered the uterine endometrial cells to exert their effect? Are they metabolized within the cells? Are they excreted with the deciduous cells during menstruation? If that's the case, the amount of circulating FSH and LH in the blood stream of hysterectomized women would be higher than the average levels of intact women and maybe that's the reason why they experience ovarian failure earlier than expected. Another possibility is that the uterus is not a passive organ, but that remains to be proved. Damage to the ovaries during surgery has been speculated, but giving the same results (early ovarian failure) after key hole procedures (laparoscopy), it seems that's not the case.